# Deploying to heroku without require_tree in application.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku

After following this [angular tutorial](http://asanderson.org/posts/2013/06/03/bootstrapping-angular-rails-part-1.html), I'm trying to deploy to heroku. I'm getting the error:

```
rake aborted!
require_tree argument must be a directory
```

The tutorial instructed me to the remove the line `//= require tree .` from application.js. When I add it back for heroku deployment, it breaks my app. Is there any workaround so I don't have to include `//= require_tree .`?

I've tried adding `//= require_tree ./mobile` and creating `/mobile` stub directory with a single file so it would commit. Didn't work.

**Edit:**

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require angular
//= require ng-infinite-scroll.min.js
//= require angular-ui-router.min.js
//= require ng-rails-csrf
```

My angular app config file:

```
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./services/global
#= require_tree ./services/main
#= require_tree ./filters/global
#= require_tree ./filters/main
#= require_tree ./controllers/global
#= require_tree ./controllers/main
#= require_tree ./directives/global
#= require_tree ./directives/main
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but my application.css.scss file includes `*= require_tree .`

Comment: Can you show us your applcation.js? It looks like you have require_tree somewhere else..

Comment: note that require_tree needs to be a relative path as well

Comment: I fixed it. I had to remove the `require global` lines b/c they were empty directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application.js looks good. You should now look into all the directories that your angluar.js config files is trying to load. Look for directories that are empty. Git does not create a physical directory if a directory is empty. Hope this helps.